# How To Configure /oauth/token ModelAndView in Spring

Tags: spring, oauth

I successfully configured an oauth spring application. However, my headache is how to make it return to the login page with a successful token; The log shows the following entry:

```
`DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling`
```

Here is my login page:

```
` <c:url value="/oauth/token" var="loginProcessingUrl"/>
 <form:form action="${loginProcessingUrl}" method="post">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Please Login</legend>
    <!-- use param.error assuming FormLoginConfigurer#failureUrl contains the query parameter error -->
    <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
        <div>
            Failed to login.
            <c:if test="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION != null}">
              Reason: <c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}" />
            </c:if>
        </div>
    </c:if>
    <!-- the configured LogoutConfigurer#logoutSuccessUrl is /login?logout and contains the query param logout -->
    <c:if test="${param.logout != null}">
        <div>
            You have been logged out.
        </div>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${param.success != null}">
        <div>
            You have been successfully been authenticated.
        </div>
    </c:if>
    <p>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
    </p>
    <!-- if using RememberMeConfigurer make sure remember-me matches RememberMeConfigurer#rememberMeParameter -->
    <p>
    <label for="remember-me">Remember Me?</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" name="remember-me"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="client_id" name="client_id" value="11111111"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="client_secret" name="client_secret" value="2222222"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="grant_type" name="grant_type" value="password"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="response_type" name="response_type" value="token"/> 
    <input type="hidden" id="redirect_uri" name="redirect_uri" value="/login?success=1"/> 
    </p>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Log in</button>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

`

And here's my spring-security.xml file:

```
`<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>`
```

Why can't I go back to the login page once a token is successfully issued. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks